# Stability of PDEs with respect to boundary data

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, boundary-value-problem

I am looking for some references that I can look into the stability of PDEs (or ODEs) with respect to boundary data.
Suppose 
$$
\mathcal{L}u_i(x) = f(x),\qquad x \in \Omega 
$$
and $u_i(x) = g_i(x)$ in $\partial \Omega$, for $i=1,2$.

For time-dependent problem, the linear stability is the notion I am looking for. However, I couldn't find any reference that shows the stability with respect to the boundary data for time-independent problem.

I am looking for some statements saying 
if $u_i^*$ are the solutions to the above PDEs, 
$$
\|u_1^* - u_2^*\| \le C \|g_1 - g_2\|,
$$
with appropriate norms.
If $\mathcal{L}$ is linear, the problem is equivalent to show that the solution to $$
\mathcal{L}u = 0, \quad x \in \Omega, \qquad u(x) = \epsilon(x) \quad x \in \partial \Omega
$$
satisfies
$\|u^*\| \le C\|\epsilon\|$.

Any answers/suggestions/comments will be very appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense to me as is. Essentially, a PDE is stable or unstable if a perturbation to the system decays or grows. When doing a linear stability analysis for a time dependent problem, your ansatz for the perturbation must respect the boundary conditions, irrespective of whether the perturbation decays or grows in time. It would seem (to me at least) that you are asking about a maximum principle for elliptic problems where the solution is bounded above by its initial condition?

Comment: @mattos You're right in the sense that I am not interested in the growth or decay of the system. Rather, for a fixed amount of time interval (for time-dependent), I am looking for a certain bound that depends on the discrepancy of boundary data. For elliptic problem, the maximum principle is the exact notion I am looking for. But I couldn't find a similar version of it for general case.